# Code works on jquery 1.8.3 but not work on 1.9.1 and up

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code that works on 1.8.3 (successfully add SUFFIX after blur or focusout when something is typed), but won't work on 1.9.1 or higher.

```
<div id="mmm">
<input type=text class="gen"><br>
<input type=text class="gen"><br>
<input type=text class="gen">
</div> 


$("#mmm").on('focusout change blur','.gen', function()  {
   var myvar=$(this);
   coreid=this.value;       
    $.ajax (
    { 

        url: '/echo/html/',
        success: function (data,status) {
            myvar.empty().attr("value", coreid + "MYSUFFIX" );
        }    
    })
})
```

Check Fiddle on 1.8.3/  If you change to version 1.9.1 or higher the code stop works (Suffix not added at end when something is typed)

http://jsfiddle.net/6nch5fp2/5/

Comment: It seems that just changing attr to prop will do the trick on this case.

Comment: `.attr("value"` not the preferred way of updating the value of an input. (you should be using `.val()`) `.empty()` is meaningless for an input element.

Comment: http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#attr-versus-prop- . Note that calling `.empty()` on an `<input>` element has no effect, since an `<input>` element doesn't have any children.

Comment: That's a good opportunity to learn the difference between HTML attributes and DOM properties.

Comment: A quick example, directly related to your question, is `.attr("value"` is (loosely) equivalent to `.prop("defaultValue"`, when clearly you want to change the value, not the default value.

Comment: empty() is gone, changed attr/prop. What about var myvar = $(this)  to access the object inside the ajax function. Is this the best approach?

Comment: *best* is too subjective. it's not necessarily a bad approach, it's one of three possible ways of doing it. The better of the three in my opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By reading [jQuery Core 1.9 Upgrade Guide](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/) you'd see what changed. Important to you is:

> jQuery 1.6 introduced the .prop() method for setting or getting
>   properties on nodes and deprecated the use of .attr() to set
>   properties. However, versions up to 1.9 continued to support using
>   .attr() for specific situations.

So change `.attr` to `.prop`:

```
$("#mmm").on('focusout change blur', '.gen', function () {
    var myvar = $(this);
    coreid = this.value;
    $.ajax({
        url: '/echo/html/',
        success: function (data, status) {
            myvar.empty().prop("value", coreid + "MYSUFFIX");
        }
    })
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/6nch5fp2/6/)**

You'll also notice that if you include the jQuery Migrate plugin that you can continue to use `.attr()`

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/adjwnath/)**

And as Terry noted below, .val() is probably the way to go regardless: `myvar.val(coreid + "MYSUFFIX");`

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/k5yf504h/)**

Comment: Actually, using `.val()` is more appropriate here.

Comment: @Terry - It may be, however I'm just pointing out to the OP what changed with regard to 1.8-1.9 in their example.